# Running jar from command line gives FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

This is the code I am running in Java project to read from a text file:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("wordsEn.txt").getFile());
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file);
```

When I run this program in Intellij IDEA, everything works fine, but when i build its JAR file, put it in my desktop, and run it through command line from my desktop with the command `java -jar SyzygiesGudrat.jar` it gives `FileNotFoundException`

Where do I have to put the text file in order to run this JAR from anywhere or in order someone else to be able to run this JAR when I send it to him?

My project structure looks like this:

[image]

Comment: You can not reference internal/embedded references as files, they are just a bunch of bytes inside a zip file. Instead make use of Class#getResourceAsStream to get a InputStream to the resource directly. Also, the resource name seems to be wordsEn.txt, not words.txt

Comment: Thanks mate. Silly me, now I am using getResourceAsStream instead of getResource. Now everything works fine. "words" was a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the code to the below one, as @MadProgrammer suggested. Now everything works fine.

```
 InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("wordsEn.txt");
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in);
```

Answer (score 0):

I stucked with the same issue.
Solution is : you can create a jar by  IDE or command prompt.
while running a jar in your folder where you store a jar must give txt file.

For example, if you save jar on desktop, then on your desktop must have txt file before you run a jar from command prompt.